# Math.sqrt in java - identify if its a complete sqrt number or not?

Tags: java

I am looking to identify method in Java 8 which says square root of any number is complete or not.

For ex:

```
Math.sqrt(25) gives 5.0
Math.sqrt(49) gives 7.0
Math.sqrt(30) gives 5.477225575051661
```

So when given number is complete sqrt, need to written true else false, how can we simply do this?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "complete"? Is `Math.sqrt(1.44)` complete?

Comment: What do you mean by "complete"?  Do you mean "square root is an integer"?  Note that `sqrt` is the function name, but the name to use when talking about the math is "square root".

Comment: Complete means its gives value washout decimal values. Why you're downvoting it ? I have clearly given example

Comment: *"I have clearly given example"* - but not generic enough examples. E.g. the root of 1.44 is 1.2 which may or may not be accepted by your code.

Comment: @JeffCook "washout"?  Do you mean "without".  Computing is about getting details right and clear.  Sorry if English is not your first language.

Comment: @JeffCook: three example don't make a specification. If your question was totally clear, I wouldn't have posted my comment abd it wouldn't have been upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the ceil or floor is equal to the number...

```
x  =  Math.sqrt(25);

if (x==Math.ceil(x)||x==Math.floor(x))
```

Comment: If `x` is an integer then `Math.ceil()` is the same value as `Math.floor()`, no need to check both. Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

You could compare the square root to the `floor` of the square root and check if they're equal:

```
public static boolean hasCompleteSqrt(double d) {
    double sqrt = Math.sqrt(d);
    return sqrt == Math.floor(sqrt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.floor:

```
double notInteger = Math.sqrt(30);
double integer = Math.sqrt(25);

notInteger == Math.floor(notInteger); // false
integer == Math.floor(integer); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if square root of number is whole number or not as below

```
 if((Math.sqrt(25)) % 1 == 0) {
                System.out.println("it is whole number");
            } else {
                System.out.println("it is not whole number");
            }
```